# Why ngOnInit is recharge

Tags: angular, ngoninit

why ngOnInit reloads after the data in firebase is modified
Here is the line of code who make ngOnInit reload

```js
this.db.database.ref("clients/" + this.user.num + "/mots_cles"+motCleOrder).set(mot.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Can you show us more? Maybe the whole `component.ts`? At least the `ngOnInit` and some relative parts.

Comment: @tomtom are you using any library or an observable for the firebase connection.